# 16 bit Kernel Has Bugs

Tags: c, windows, gcc, operating-system, kernel

It is a while now , i am dealing with Operating System and development . So i started on a project with MinGW compiler (GCC) in windows . I thought of creating a 16 bit operating system and a mini DOS first before jumping to protected mode . I started out for it's development . Everyting was going well but when i for the first time compiled and executed the Operating System in Boschs , a very suprising thing happened . I was trying to print welcome to my Operating System and take some inputs from the user using shell style but on the screen no text came out , only the cursor is blinking . I am very confused why it happended , i looked down the code and there were bugs , i fixed them and re-tried but it failed . At last i need help !

## What I am using

1. C Compiler (GCC) (CodeBlocks MinGW).
2. NASM Assembler.
3. Linker and objcopy etc (provided with CodeBlocks MinGW).
4. Boschs Emulator.

## What are the errors

1. Nothing is printed on the screen.
2. Sometimes 'virutal_read_byte_32 : segment limit violation' error is given by Boschs.

## What help I need

1. Fix any bugs in the program and explain your solution.

## Code

## Kernel.c

```
asm(".code16 \n");

int strlen(const char *str)
{
    int cnt = 0;

    while(str[cnt] != 0)
    {
      cnt++;
    }  

    return cnt;
}

void printChar(char ch)
{
   asm volatile ("mov ah , 0x0e");
   asm volatile ("mov al , %0" : : "r" (ch));
   asm volatile ("int 0x10"); 
}

void printf(const char *str)
{
  int len = strlen(str);
  int cnt = 0;

  while(cnt < len)
  {
    printChar(str[cnt]); 
  }
}

void kmain( )
{
    printf("Welcome to My Operating System!");
    jmp:
      // Hang.
    goto jmp; 
}
```

## Boot.asm

```
[org 0x7c00] ;
[bits 16] ;

  mov [boot_drive] , dl ;
  mov bp , 0x9000 ;
  mov sp , bp ;

  mov bx , miniOS_booting ;
  call print_string ;

  call delay ;
  call newline ;

  mov bx , miniOS_bootdone ;
  call print_string ;

  call delay ;

  mov bx , 0x1000 ;
  mov dh , 1 ;
  mov dl , [boot_drive] ;
  call disk_load ;

  mov ah , 0x0 ;
  mov al , 0x2 ;
  int 0x10 ;

  jmp 0000:0x1000 ;
  jmp $ ;

disk_load:
      mov ah , 2 ; Read Sector Function
      mov al , dh  ; Number of sectors to read
      mov dh , 0 ; Head
      mov ch , 0 ; Track / Cylinder
      mov cl , 2 ; Start From 

      int 0x13 ;

      jc disk_error ;  
   ret ;

disk_error:
       call newline ;
       mov bx , miniOS_boot_error ;
       call print_string ;
       jmp $ ;

newline:
      pusha;
      mov ah , 0x0e ;
      mov al , 10 ;
      int 0x10 ;
      mov al , 13 ;
      int 0x10 ;
      popa ;
      ret ;

print_string:
    pusha;
        mov ah, 0x0e ;
        pnt:
         mov al , [bx] ;
         cmp al , 0 ;
         je done ;
         int 0x10 ;
         add bx , 1;
         jmp pnt ;
    done:
    popa;
    ret;

delay:
MOV     CX, 0FH
MOV     DX, 4240H
MOV     AH, 86H
INT     15H    
ret ;

miniOS_booting:
   db 'Booting Mini OS .' , 0 ;

miniOS_bootdone:
   db 'Booting Done .' , 0 ;

miniOS_boot_error:
   db 'Error Booting.' , 0 ;

boot_drive:
     db 0 ; 

times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0;   
dw 0xaa55 ;
```

## Entry.asm

```
[bits 16]
[extern _kmain]

___main:
call _kmain ;

jmp $ ;
```

## Commands

```
nasm -f bin Boot.asm -o Boot.bin
nasm -f elf Entry.asm -o Entry.o
gcc -ffreestanding -c Kernel.c -o Kernel.o -masm=intel
ld -T NUL -Ttext 0x1000 -o Kernel.tmp Entry.o Kernel.o
objcopy -O binary -j .text Kernel.tmp Kernel.bin
copy /b Boot.bin+Kernel.bin OS
```

## Boschs

```
floppya : 1_44 = OS , status = inserted
boot : a
```

Thanks to all the users for helping me solve this problem.

Comment: Don't code a 16 bits kernel. You'll be hurt by a lot of limitations. Also notice that you are using a 32 bits compiler.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Sokrates Starynkiewicz

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/737545/Writing-a-bit-dummy-kernel-in-C-Cplusplus here is the link which shows a 16 bit kernel.

Comment: As you see on my home page, Sokrates Starynkevitch was my ancestor...

Comment: @user43609, what does the linker script `NUL` contains?

Comment: @B.Shankar: `NUL` is the null device, presumably equivalent to an empty file in this context.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a 'Fix any bugs in the program and explain your solution' debug-slave request.

Comment: NUL means , don't use linker scripts.;